# Cloudflare streaming tag 'autoplay' not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, cloudflare

My autoplay option of Cloudflare Stream tag is working perfectly on Safari, Chrome and desktop browsers but is not working on IOS.

[image: As you can see the video loads perfectly, but I have to press play to start.]

Is there a way to start the video? Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Videos on iOS will not start playing unless there is a user action on it.

If you want to autoplay a video in iOS, you have to play it as **MUTED**.

Also this workaround will not work --> **autoplaying as muted, then unmute programatically as soon as the video starts**.

> One note though:   autoplay on iOS will not work at all if power saving mode is ON.